# Can I by pass oauth authorization to hit my rest service in local ? or is it compulsory to have oauth settings to run Rest through postman?

Tags: rest, api, oauth, postman

I have started new Rest service and want to test it through postman, I am able to run my rest through docker in my local, but can I just bypass oauth token for testing or is it compulsory to have oauth to run the service through postman ?

Comment: It really depends on your implementation. If you have hard coded the authorization logic then it you must pass auth token ,But if implementation provide way to disable authorization then you can hit rest without any auth  token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can bypass OAuth in local. If you are using spring boot, in your SecurityConfig file just give
aHttp.authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().permitAll();

And in application.properties file add- security.ignored=/**

This would bypass all security.

Comment: I am not using spring boot.. I had web.xml and service profile yaml file.. is there any thing I can do over those files to by pass the oauth ?

Comment: Add  this line in yaml file.  security.ignored=/**